# android studio download for android phone

Tags: android

Looking for a android studio / sdk that will download to a smartphone. Have been to the android site and selected download but it does not seem to complete and it does not download. Please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an app you can use for this purpose.

[AIDE-IDE for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dandroid%20ide&pcampaignid=APPU_1_JwbLV4TFG4vjU5unpYAE)

There is no version of android studio for android platform so there is no way you can download and run it on android.

And read this [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)